# SQL Server : combine 2 stored procedures into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 stored procedures, and my goal is to combine these into one so
I can use filter to select value CHOOSE.

Thank you.

```
EXEC dbo.newcombine @startdate = 'yyyy-mm-dd', @enddate = 'yyyy-mm-dd', @choose = 'testone' OR @choose = 'testwo'
```

First stored procedure:

```
    @choose nvarchar(10)
    set @choose = testone

     @startdate date 
    ,@enddate date 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        c.TypeofCall
    FROM
        Contact c
     AND c.callin BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
END
```

Second stored procedure:

```
    @choose nvarchar(10)
    set @choose = testtwo

     @startdate date
    ,@enddate date
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        c.TypeofService
    FROM
        Contact c
    AND c.callin BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
END
```

Comment: You should provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want your stored procedure to do.  "Combine" is not particularly descriptive.

Comment: If I use filter CHOOSE  = testone then will return value for  c.TypeofCall . If I use filter CHOOSE  = testtwo then will return value for  c.TypeofService

Comment: why you need to combine 2 SP ? , from you queries i can see its a same scheme, only the field in select to return value is diferent ...you can use if statment or use sql case statment in same select query https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I will need it on the SSRS report so I can use CHOOSE parameter  for filter

Comment: You should post the **complete and actual** code - not just some fragments that don't really make up a real, functioning procedure....

Comment: This is actual code. it's simple

Comment: Can you  use like IF  THEN somehow?

Comment: You're not showing the whole header of the stored procedures, and both your `SELECT` have no `WHERE` clause - just an `AND ....` portion - the `@startdate` and `@endate` is neither clearly parameters, nor is there a `DECLARE` in sight .... - that code **cannot possibly** run ...

Comment: I just removed them for easy to read.

Comment: Let cancel the question. Thank you